# Python POST requests to an API with JSON data work on Requestbin, but not locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, http, python-requests

I'm making API calls to a server with Python's Requests library. Locally, I have the JSON data in a directory, all files ending with .json. I am importing a JSON file to my Python file like so:

```
with open("./json_payloads/data.json") as user_file:
    json_data = user_file.read()
```

The type `json_data` is String and in JSON format. When I try the API POST request, I get back a 500 error from the server.

When doing it from Requestbin, I do everything exactly the same except instead of pulling JSON from a file, I have it in Requestbin's data store. I pull it like so:

```
  data_store = pd.inputs["data_store"]
  json_data = data_store["json_data"]
```

And I get back a 200 result from the server.

Any insights on why this is not working locally? I would much rather complete this locally for later steps in the process, like when I will upload files.

Comment: instead of phrases like 'try the API POST request', or 'doing it from Requestbin', attach the raw code that can reproduce the steps, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_data` read from the file is of type `str`. Convert it to a `dict` using `json.loads` before sending it with a request.

```
import json
json_data = json.loads(json_data)
```

Comment: Better yet, replace the `user_file.read()` call altogether with `json.load(user_file)`.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!!!!!!!!!! I can't tell you how much I was stressing over this today. Totally worked!